# Is there a JUnit equivalent of NUnit's TestCaseAttribute?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

In NUnit, I can do something like this:

```
[TestCase(12,3,4)]
[TestCase(12,2,6)]
[TestCase(12,4,3)]
public void DivideTest(int n, int d, int q)
{
  Assert.AreEqual( q, n / d );
}
```

and it will run 3 test cases with each set of parameters. Is there a way to do something like this in JUnit4? I tried to google it and only came up with something like this: [Parameterized unit tests with JUnit 4](https://blogs.oracle.com/jacobc/entry/parameterized_unit_tests_with_junit) which is far more complicated and verbose than the above NUnit example.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [junitparams](http://code.google.com/p/junitparams/)  you can then write code like this:

```java
@Test
@Parameters({ "17, false", 
              "22, true" })
public void personIsAdult(int age, boolean valid) throws Exception {
  assertThat(new Person(age).isAdult(), is(valid));
}
```

(Example from the above link)

You have to use the annotation `@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)` to run the tests with `JUnitParamsRunner` rather than the normal`JUint` runner

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  Parameterized tests are the closest thing that I am aware of.